# WooCommerce get color code from single variation

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I am using `Variation Swatches` plugin.
I have attributed named color and want to get a color code for each attribute.

Furthermore, I'm accessing single variation this way, and it worked:

```
$single_variation = new WC_Product_Variation( $value );

$terms = get_terms( [
    'taxonomy'   => 'pa_color',
    'hide_empty' => false,
] );

foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
    $color = get_term_meta( $term->term_id )["product_attribute_color"][0];
    //break;
}
```

This code returns me only the first color code. How to connect and get current for variation?

Comment: How do you decide between the current and the other ones? I don't understand your code - I've really tried.

Comment: Always gived to me first of array